# Stepping through Visual Studio Debugger with F10/F11 behaves like F5 (Run)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I have been running into a strange Visual Studio (2010) issue when debugging the a solution and I’m hoping someone has some thoughts on how to fix this issue.

At times, during debugging when hitting a break point and start stepping through (F10 or F11) the behavior seen is that of F5 (run), immediately jumping out of the debugger with the page rendered. If a break point is set it’ll run to that but from there it will run to end (or next break point).

The only thing I’ve found to stop this behavior (for a short while) is to close Visual Studio, shutdown IIS, close out IE (yeah, have to do this, seems to hold references) and then go and purge all of the Temporary ASP.NET Files found in all Framework folders (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET).

This is really making debugging and troubleshooting difficult. Any thoughts on what might be causing this (and how to fix)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had issues with multithreaded debugging in Visual Studio (we use VS 2008 with C# code).  Sometimes the debugger would hang, and other times it would just continue the debugging session.

I finally found a workaround for my issues.  I selected Visual Studio Tools/Options, Debugging, General, and disabled “Call string conversion function on objects in variables windows (C# and JavaScript only)”.

Internet posts also suggested un-checking “Enable property evaluation and other implicit calls”, but I didn’t need to do that in my case.

Comment: So far using the first suggestion appears to be working for me and a co-worker who was also experiencing the same issue. It's only been a day but so far so good. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting this problem in Visual Studio Community 2017 v15.8.1. 
Unchecking "Call string conv..." and "Enable property eval..." doesn;t change anything. I'm still getting Step Over(F10) intermittently behaving like Run(F5)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.

I got it resolved by installing the update for SP1  [KB 957912](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB957912/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1796) for Visual Studio 2008.

There will be updates for VS2010, too, I guess.